# Generating Dynamic Pygal Chart in Flask

Tags: python, flask, pygal

I am trying to create a Pygal chart and display it in flask - without saving the .svg file. Is this possible? Every Combination i have tried has given me an error.
template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %} {{chart}} {% endblock %}
```

Views:

```
@app.route('/chart')
def test():
bar_chart = pygal.HorizontalStackedBar()
bar_chart.title = "Remarquable sequences"
bar_chart.x_labels = map(str, range(11))
bar_chart.add('Fibonacci', [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55])
bar_chart.add('Padovan', [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12]) 
chart = bar_chart.render()
return render_template('test.html', chart=chart )
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: What if you run the app in debug mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Python 2.7 you will need to use this:

```
@app.route('/chart')
def test():
    bar_chart = pygal.HorizontalStackedBar()
    bar_chart.title = "Remarquable sequences"
    bar_chart.x_labels = map(str, range(11))
    bar_chart.add('Fibonacci', [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55])
    bar_chart.add('Padovan', [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12]) 
    chart = bar_chart.render(is_unicode=True)
    return render_template('test.html', chart=chart )
```

And to render the graph in the template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %} {{chart|safe}} {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I just tried this - it's still not generating the graph. I'm using flask if that is any help?

Answer (score 3):

```
import pygal

@app.route('/something.svg')
def graph_something():
    bar_chart = pygal.Bar()
    bar_chart.add('Fibonacci', [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55])
    return bar_chart.render_response()
```

and then just have your html file refer to that:

```
<body>
  <figure>
    <embed type="image/svg+xml" src="/mysvg.svg" />
  </figure>
</body>
```